# IntelliJ undo remember checkboxes

Tags: intellij-idea

On "VCS Update" I usually got a dialog where I could choose some git functions like stash, rebase etc.
Today I accidentally klicked that "remember" checkbox and don't know how to undo this. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Preferences/Version Control/Confirmation* and check *Update* under the *Display options dialog when these commands are invoked*.

[image]

On a related note, all of the *Do not display in the future* choices can be revoked in the corresponding sections of the settings (for instance the reformat code dialog).